# Flutter Map or .fromJson of my not working

Tags: flutter, dart, fromjson

I have data response with api and i can't map it to List but it return users null, i think is not working because method fromJson

this is data return with api
[image: This is data return with API]

and this is my models
[image: Models and method fromJson]

My controller
[image]

end is Debug window
[image]

Thanks for any answer

Comment: Please in the future copy-paste your code into the question instead of putting a screenshot, it makes it easier to answer.

Comment: thanks your comment i will note and next time i will follow it @h8moss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you further specify what it is that you get as a result? Is the whole list full of null? Or are some of the objects' fields null?

Here is what I believe is an error:

```
nameUser: json['tenNguoiDung'] == null ? '' : json['ten']
avatarUser: json['nguoiDung_anhDinhKem'] == null ? '' : json['avatar'],
```

You are saying:

> If `tenNguoiDung` is null: nameUser is equal to '', if it isn't, nameUser = json['ten'].

But your json doesn't have a 'ten' field, so it will be null. What you are most likely looking for is the if-null operator:

```
nameUser: json['tenNguoiDung'] ?? ''
avatarUser: json['nguoiDung_anhDinhKem'] ?? ''
```

which will assign `''` if the json field is null.

Comment: thanks your answer i did flow your answer and success. again thanks

Comment: Happy to help ^^